# PostgreSQL Timestamp Difference in Milliseconds

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I am struggling getting the difference of two Timestamps in milliseconds.

My current approach was

```sql
SELECT * FROM EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM(NOW()::TIMESTAMP - '2022-10-23 16:34:53.227'))
```

which was described on a bad website as returning the difference in seconds but in fact returning the difference defined as an interval.

It so happens, that i am unable to multiply a factor of 1000 to get the value as milliseconds.
I've then tried to cast the result as numeric or decimal, bigint, int8 and int but none these want let me use any calculation nor comparison.

Can someone tell me, what i am misunderstanding here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `SELECT * FROM EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM(NOW()::TIMESTAMP - '2022-10-23 16:34:53.227'))` **does not** return an interval: `SELECT * FROM pg_typeof(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM(NOW()::TIMESTAMP - '2022-10-23 16:34:53.227'))); numeric`. Where the `numeric` value is the number of seconds between the two  timestamps.

Comment: Silly syntax error. The `* FROM` right after `SELECT` is your problem; omit it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe oh wow yeah that works. do you want to post this as an answer instead of a comment? 
I would like to understand the technical behaviour here. Any operator does not work until i change the syntax like you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM(NOW()::TIMESTAMP - '2022-10-23 16:34:53.227'))*1000 as DESIRED_COLUMN_NAME
```

You could also simplify to:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM(NOW() - '2022-10-23 16:34:53.227'))*1000 as DESIRED_COLUMN_NAME
```

You can check it with this too:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM(CAST('2022-10-23 17:45:12.000' AS TIMESTAMP)- '2022-10-23 17:45:00.000'))*1000 AS milliseconds
```

It outputs 12000

Comment: Just a note to your "simplify". I do the cast to get rid of the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Take the epoch form both timestamp and subtract it

```
select
  extract('epoch' from NOW())  - extract('epoch' from '2022-10-23 16:34:53.227'::timestamp)
```

| ?column? |
| --- |
| 18464.130495 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hyeLoLA7)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM(NOW() - (NOW() - '0:0:0.256134'::interval)) * 1000) ;
  extract   
------------
 256.134000
```